# left outer join 3 tables in linq to sql

Tags: linq, join

I was trying to write a query in linq where I join 3 tabels and fill in the null values with the string "ANY" but this is not happening need some help please i am new at this.

I tried doing something like this...

```
var results = from user in allusers
              join building in allbuildings where building.buildingid equals user.buildingid
              into BuildingAndUsers.FirstorDefault(new allbuildings{BuildingName="ANY" BuildingID=0})
              from blah in BuildingAndUsers
              join Site in AllSites where ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
var results = 
      from user in allusers
      join building in allbuildings on building.buildingid equals user.buildingid
          into BuildingAndUsers 
      from buildingAndUser in BuildingAndUsers.DefaultIfEmpty(new allbuildings { BuildingName="ANY", BuildingID=0 })
      join Site in AllSites on ....
          into BuildingAndUsersAndSites
      from buildingAndUsersAndSite in BuildingAndUsersAndSites.DefaultIfEmpty()
      select ...
```

Comment: cool this is working...
Now i need to add default values to the rest of the joins as well how do i go about doing that any help..??

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse: the same way as it done for the first join, nothing else.

Comment: @VishweshwarKapse: if the answer solved the issue, mark it as the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions)